Programmatically Execute SSIS .dtsx Packages with C# for SQL Server 2019?
I am trying to programmatically execute SSIS .dtsx packages using a C# application targeting SQL Server 2019. Previously, I was using NuGet package for SQL Server 2016, but after migrating the SSIS packages to SQL Server 2019, I needed a new solution.
To address this, I created a custom NuGet package that includes the following DLLs:

Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
Microsoft.SQLServer.PipelineHost.dll

However, when running the application, it fails to execute the SSIS package. I suspect that additional dependencies might be missing or there might be compatibility issues with SQL Server 2019.
Here's what I've done so far:
Verified Installed Components:
I have SQL Server 2019 with the Integration Services feature installed.
The required DLLs were extracted from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn and added to my custom NuGet package.
Additional Troubleshooting:
Checked the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) for related dependencies.
Verified the existence of the following additional DLLs but haven’t included them explicitly in my project:

Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipeline.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsMsg.dll

Issue Encountered:
The application does not throw a specific error during compilation but fails at runtime when attempting to execute the SSIS package.
Are there any additional DLLs required to execute SSIS packages on SQL Server 2019?
Should I be including other libraries like Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll?
Is there a better or official approach to handle SSIS package execution for SQL Server 2019 for C#?
How can I ensure the compatibility of the referenced DLLs with SQL Server 2019?

It is much better to launch SSIS package from c# via T-SQL. This way there are no dependencies' on any external assemblies. You can package T-SQL as a stored procedure. Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16

we are currently for a similar solution, because we have a lot of ssis packages, otherwise we have to migrate all the packages

You only need to deploy the packages on the server so they appear in SSISDB. We have lots of packages that we allow users to run on demand for transferring data in workflows etc. These are all called from T-SQL (which we actually use SSRS to configure an submit the jobs that run the packages - but that's jus the front end)
